# Skipping 0 in a for loop array based off a predefined integer

Tags: java

I'm looping through numbers to create an array. The rowInput is based off user input and can be a number between 7 and 10. I need the array I'm creating to be
 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 if the rowInput is 7 etc but the code below gives me 0,1,2,3,4,5,6 .

Is there anyway to skip the number 0 or do I need to create an array of rowInput+1 and then remove the first element or similar.

```
for(int i = 1; i < rowInput; i++) 
{ 
    numberArray[i] = i;
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numberArray));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for(int i = 0; i < rowInput; i++) 
{ 
    numberArray[i] = i + 1;
}
```

Comment: beaten by 2 seconds XD

Comment: @JavaSprinter if it works perfectly click on a gray tick below the answer score - this will mark it as solution. Read [ask] in your free time.

Answer (score 0):

Array always starts with index 0.

Solution:
numberArray[i-1] = i ;